# What is the approach to merge data from multiple databases (same schema) using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have 3 OLTP databases, all using the same database schema. Each db represents one department.

I am exploring Power BI as a solution for reporting at the company level, so all departments combined.

What is the approach to combine data from multiple dbs into a data warehouse? For example - do I need SSIS to combine the 3 dbs into 1 data warehouse?

Another option could be to have 1 shared dataset per db, and then the final report can connect and combine multiple live datasets? Or is there another way with Power BI like combining multiple live datasets?

Any reference link on how if someone has done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there another way with Power BI

Yes.  Simply create a single import model and load data from all three databases in it.  So for each table in your Power BI model you would have three Power Queries set to not load into the model, and you would append them in a query that is used to load your model.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries

Comment: The same table in each database has its own primary key for example id 2 will be shared by multiple dimension rows (ID 2 maybe mango in db1, whereas ID 2 maybe apple in db2). How to handle this in dimension, fact and the link between dim and fact?

Comment: One approach is to transform the dimension key values so they are globally unique on load.  So 2 -> 10002, 20002, 30002 depending on which database it comes from.

Comment: Ok say I have 1 query per table per db, and then I append the respective queries to form the final tables, then can I make use of incremental refresh feature?

Comment: Yep.  You can apply the RangeStart/RangeEnd to the loading query and it will fold into each source query.  Of course you can _also_ apply the parameters to the non-loading source queries.

Comment: If I apply Incremental concept to the non loading (that is the append query), then will this concept trickle down to the individual power queries and source db?

Comment: The append query is the "loading" one, ie the one that is loaded into your DataSet, and at least for SQL Server the range parameters are "folded" into the source query and so the filtering happens in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to:

1. Extract the data into a single database (DWH or reporting schema)
2. Build the necessary items there for your data model, be it reporting schema, or star/snowflake schemas
3. Connect Power BI to that schema.

Combining datasets is going to be tricky, you may have the same measures in each of the datasets. Combining in the database, with any added columns to indicate the department is the best option in terms of supporting updating/adding/removing items. For example, if the schema changes in the DB's you do it in one place, not three datasets. The toolset in DB/SSIS will be better suited to the heavy lifting of the data to a location.

You would use SSIS to extract the data if on-prem data, Azure Data Factory for Azure DB's. Extract to a staging schema, convert/transform the data into its final from, with a new schema to define what it is, facts/dimensions other schema names such as reporting can be used, depending on the data model you wish to build. Most of this is covered by the standard ETL pattern of OLTP to an OLAP database.